How can I tell if my home has an electrode grounding system?
I have a 1960s home located in Georgia with brick exterior where the outside electrical meter is located. My breaker panel is located close to the middle interior of the house on 2nd floor.
I have pulled a permit and one of the electrical companies I had quote out the job said the city would check to see if I have an electrode grounding system (this is nothing close to the scope of work I have in my permit btw). He didn’t look around to see if I might potentially have one but instead just added 1.2k on the quote.
I originally thought all homes had an electrode grounding system. If this is the case, where would mine most likely be? And if I even have one would I even be able to see the set up? Don’t know if it is helpful information but my electric meter is not near my water main line or hot water heater.
Attach is the exterior meter. The green line is from phone company that says it’s a ground wire.


While generally speaking an inspector should only be looking at the work included in the permit, they can look at other stuff. For example, when I had a panel replacement, my electrician told me the inspector might check for sufficient smoke detectors based on current rules (which have changed significantly over time) even though none of the permitted work had anything to do with smoke detectors. The inspector didn't look at smoke detectors, but he could have.
Similarly, the local inspectors might look for the condition of the grounding electrode system even if that is not in the permitted work. Why? For one thing, many older ground wires connect to copper water mains. But if a plumber replaced some pipes with plastic - which may or may not require a permit but certainly wouldn't require an electrical permit - then the grounding path could be interrupted without you knowing it until there was a problem. Or the wire outside from the panel to ground rod(s) may be damaged after decades of weather, landscaping work, etc.
That being said, the electrician could/should have done a quick look to check your existing grounding - it really isn't that hard to do in most cases. And an extra $1,200 to add grounding (if indeed it needs replacement) sounds very high to me.
The one thing that sounds really strange is "breaker panel is located close to the middle interior of the house on 2nd floor". Normally the main panel is located:

Outside next to the meter
Inside on the other side of the same wall that has the meter on the outside

with the idea that the unprotected wiring between meter and main breaker should be as short as practical. Having the main panel in the middle of the house doesn't generally make much sense. But if it is in the middle of the house and you need new ground wires, that could require significant work, though $1,200 still sounds high.
But one possibility is that you actually have either an emergency disconnect outside next to the meter or, possibly, an actual "main panel", even if it only has a few spaces and most of your circuits are inside. If the "main panel" is outside then that's where the ground wire goes, and then it is usually very easy to run to ground rods.

I added picture of outside meter if that helps. Don’t know if it would be considered my main panel. I am unable to open it though as it is locked by my power company. The green wire says it’s the ground wire from phone company.

That box is only a meter box, no breakers/disconnect/etc. (there are combos, but that's not one of them). The green wire is kind of funny, because the phone company probably puts that in just by default, but it is quite possible that the meter box is not grounded at all.

So for electrode grounding system, would it have to be grounding rods connected to my meter box (assuming I don’t have because I can see any rods or anything) OR my meter box connected to the water main? Would my interior panel give any clues?

It is: grounding wire to main panel, wherever that may be. This meter box is not your main panel, though I am still skeptical about "middle of the house, 2nd floor" - so pictures of that panel would help - there may be another panel someplace else in between. But from the main panel it is one of: 2 ground rods; 2 ground rods and water pipe, 1 ground rod and water pipe. Which? Varies by jurisdiction.
